# Setting Up "Reply To" button in Lotus Notes

Tags: email, lotus-notes, code

This should be simple but I can't figure it out. I am building a template that a group of people will be sending out. Instead of a button that sends a "Mailto:" command I need one that will REPLY (with or without attachments) to the sender of the email.

I can't program in a specific email for it to go to. Possible?

Comment: Are the emails going to be staying internal to notes or using internet email?  Also, are using using formula language or html or what in your template?

Comment: They will be going to external users. All senders will be internal Lotus Notes users so I can probably use either HTML or Formulas.

Comment: Here's a simple how to video on how to setup a REPLY TO field. Easy.
<https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RcDUm0APjHI>

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that formula language is translated by the Domino router during SMTP/MIME conversion the way it is by Domino's HTTP server.  So I don't think you can use formula language.

And I don't think there's an equivalent to the "mailto:" URL that causes the receiving mail client to generate a reply.  It's not a Notes restriction.  It's just not part of the standards.  I checked out the [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) for mailto syntax, and it doesn't seem to be covered.

The only thing I think you can do is set the Reply-To header in the outbound message, and give the recipients instructions in the text telling them to use the Reply or Reply with Attachments feature of their mail program.  To actually set the Reply-To header, just set the ReplyTo field in the Notes message.

Comment: you can construct the mailto link so that it generates an email with a specific subject, to:, and body.  So you could have it make the subject be "re: whatever" and when they click it, it'll open pre-populate the subject in their mail client.